# ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘plotly’

Tags: r, installation, plotly

I am having difficulties installing Plotly

I get this ERROR text:

```
    Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2017c.1.0/zoneinfo/Europe/London'
* installing *source* package ‘plotly’ ...
** package ‘plotly’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/tidyr/libs/tidyr.so':
  dlopen(/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/tidyr/libs/tidyr.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libc++.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/tidyr/libs/tidyr.so
  Reason: image not found
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘plotly’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.4/site-library/plotly’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plotly’ had non-zero exit status
```

I google it but still can't find any answer. 
Does anybody know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reinstalled the tidyr package and tried again installing plotly finally worked. I hope this will be of help to somebody.